# Proving that the Octonion Norm Respects Multiplication

Tags: quaternions, division-algebras, octonions

I'm working with the following definition of the octonions: $\mathbb{O} = \mathbb{H} \times \mathbb{H}$, endowed with the product $$(p,q)(r,s) = (pr - sq^*, p^*s + rq).$$ Conjugation is given by $(p,q)^* = (p^*, -q)$, and for each $P \in \mathbb{O}$, we define a norm $|P|^2 = P^*P$. I'm having a surprising amount of trouble showing that $|PQ| = |P||Q|$ for all $P,Q \in \mathbb{O}$. I'm aware of the following two identities: $(PQ^*)Q = P(Q^*Q)$ and $P^*(PQ) = (P^*P)Q$. This doesn't seem to get me there, for I have no way of rewriting the expression $(PQ)^*(PQ) = (Q^*P^*)(PQ)$ in a way that gets me closer to $(P^*P)(Q^*Q)$. I've tried going back to the definition of octonion multiplication and writing everything in terms of quaternions, but this gets ugly very fast and seems to require that I go even one layer deeper and write everything in terms of complex numbers, which is far too tedious. Is there a clean way to prove this identity, using just the tools I've mentioned?

Edit: Here's my currect progress: $|P|^2|Q|^2 = (P^*P)(Q^*Q) = ((P^*P)Q^*)Q = (Q^*(P^*P))Q$, where I have used one of the above identities together with the fact that $P^*P$ is real and thus commutes with everything. This gets the terms in the same order as $(Q^*P^*)(PQ)$, but the grouping is still different.

Edit 2: The technique of expressing everything in terms of quaternions relies on proving that the following expression is zero, with $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{H}$: $$rqs^*p + (rqs^*p)^* - qs^*pr - (qs^*pr)^*.$$The noncommutativity of quaternions is an obstacle here.

Comment: Octonion multiplication is $\Bbb R$-bilinear, you only need to check your equations for the basis elements..

Comment: Conceptually, why it's true is because any two elements generate a quaternion or commutative subalgebra.

Answer (score 2):

Using that $(xy)^* = y^*x^*$, you get
$$|xy|^2 = (xy)^*(xy) = y^*x^*xy = (x^*x)(y^*y) = |x|^2|y|^2 \,.$$

The identity $(xy)^* = y^*x^*$ can be verified directly from the definitions.
(By induction, you may assume that it holds in the quaternions, since
$\mathbb{H}=\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$
with multiplication defined in the same way as for $\mathbb{O}$.)

Comment: This is what I've been going for but I'm confused about the second and 3rd equal sign in your centered line: the 3rd one makes sense if $x^*x$ is a real number - is this true? For the 2nd, why are we allowed to move the parentheses around, or remove them entirely like you did? Octonion multiplication isn't associative.

Comment: In an alternative algebra such as the octonions, any subalgebra generated by two elements is associative. Consequently, any subalgebra of the octonions generated by a single element is commutative and associative, and thus a field. Thus $\langle a\rangle =\mathrm{span}\{1, a\} \simeq \mathbb{C}$ for any $a\in\mathbb{O}\setminus\mathbb{R}1$. Inside of the subalgebra $\langle a \rangle$, the involution $a\mapsto a^*$ is just complex conjugation. In particular, $a^*a = aa^*\in\mathbb{R}1$ for all $a\in\mathbb{O}$.

Comment: Everything in the displayed equation takes place in the subalgebra $\langle x,y \rangle \subset \mathbb{O}$, generated by the elements $x$ and $y$. This subalgebra is associative, so removing the brackets in this expression is ok.